# How to pass values from an integer array to string array with blank spaces in C

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have my `int array` and my array of `char`:

```
int arr[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
char str[80];
```

So, I'm trying to pass the `int array` values to my `char array` with blank spaces, because I'll insert this values inside a `FILE`.

So, my `char array` should be like this: `0 1 2 3 4 5` (with blank spaces).

How I can do this?

I can pass the `int` values to my `char array`, but without blank spaces. This is my code:

```
FILE *myFile;
char str[80],c;
int vet[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int i;

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    str[i] = vet[i]+'0';
    str[i+1] = " "; //blank space
}

printf("%s", str);

if(!(myFile = fopen("file.txt","w"))){
  printf("Error!\n");
  exit(1);
}

fprintf(myFile, str);
fclose(myFile);
```

Comment: You're using the same indices for str and vet. You need to use 2*i and 2*i+1 for your str ones, and you need to zero-terminate the string too.

Comment: `str[i+1] = " ";` Your compiler isn't warning you about this?

Comment: from the context of your code it looks like you want this to be a string? If so, you'll need to do some kind of conversion, there's a difference between the integer `0` and the character `'0'`. You can use something like [`sprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) or add `'0'` to each value of your array.

Comment: @Rup Thanks a lot! I was overwriting the values. Now it's clean for me

Comment: @Shawn Not! I'm using codeBlokcs in Windows 10

Comment: @yano Thanks a lot for the link, a very good contribution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str[i] = vet[i]+'0'` This is a very hacky way of doing this and will ONLY work for the numbers 0-9. Here's why if you don't already know:

The numbers 0-9 got decimal values, well, 0-9 obviously. Here's the decmial values for the ASCII characters for 0-9

```
'0' = 48
'1' = 49
'2' = 50
'3' = 51
'4' = 52
'5' = 53
'6' = 54
'7' = 55
'8' = 56
'9' = 57
```

So by putting for example `4 +'0'` into the char array you are actually adding 52. The formating `%s` is what makes printf interpret this as an ASCII code instead of an integer. You can try to do `str[0] = 52;` and that would still print the character 4 as the first character in the string if used with `%s`

Now if you do `10 + '0'` you will add 58, which is the ASCII code for `:`

To get around this you can use the function `sprintf()`
It can print the number as a string into the provided buffer. Keep in mind that 10 does not exist as one character but is instead a string containing 1 and 0. Example code:

```
FILE *myFile;

char str[80];
char *p = str;

int vet[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int i;

for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    //Take the number at vet[i] and print it as a string to the buffer.
    //The pointer is increased by the amount of characters written
    p = sprintf(p, "%d ", vet[i]);
}

//Remove trailing space
str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';

printf("%s", str);

if(!(myFile = fopen("file.txt","w"))){
    printf("Error!\n");
    exit(1);
}

fprintf(myFile, str);
fclose(myFile);
```

This should work for any number in the vet array

Comment: You probably want to check this [itoa implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/lk/+/qcom-dima-8x74-fixes/lib/libc/itoa.c)

Comment: It works because you have used `calloc` which internally sets all the bytes to '0' since you are overwriting `\0` with `' '` (`str[strlen(str)] = ' ';`)

Comment: I see. itoa is not a standard C function. Edited the answer with `sprintf()` instead. And yes, that was the reason I used calloc. Just to avoid having to deal with the null terminator

Comment: Rather than iterate over the `str[]` repeatedly with `strlen()`, code code use the return value of `sprintf()` --> `char *p = str; for(i=0; i<5; i++){ p += sprintf(p, "%d ", vet[i]); }`.

Comment: Indeed chux! This makes it much better. Also no need for calloc anymore. Edited answer

Comment: `str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';` to remove the final `' '` is OK.  `p[-1] = '\0';` is a quick alternative.  Many possibilities.

Comment: @chux Interesting. Didn't know you could index using negative numbers. I'm not used to working with pointer incrementation. Hence my love for inefficient use of `strlen()`

Comment: remembering that it is necessary to increment the pointer `p`: `p += sprintf(p, "%d ", vet[i]);`

Comment: Thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the `' '` with next number and `str[i+1] = " ";` is wrong you need to use single quotes `' '`. Once you are done with the copying *null* `\0` terminate the string as below.

```
int i = 0;
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    str[2*i] = vet[i]+'0';
    str[2*i+1] = ' '; //blank space
}
str[2*i-1] = '\0'; // Append \0 char here.
printf("%s", str);
```

Comment: I suggest terminating the string with `str[2*i-1] = '\0';` to overwrite the unwanted final trailing space.

Comment: Using `[i]` and [i+1]` I was overwriting the value. Now it's clear for me. Thank's a lot for you help @kiran!